# Sku on Admin Order Info

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, sku

I need to have SKU on order info in admin panel "OC3.0.2.0". Is here anybody can show me the way to solve this small problem.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Open order.php in admin/controller/sale

Find this

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

Replace it by

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);
$sku = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);

$data['products'][] = array(
```

Find this in the same file

```
'model'            => $product['model'],
```

add after

```
'sku'              => $sku['sku'],
```

Now Open order.php from admin/Langauge/en-gb/sale

Find for

```
$_['column_model']               = 'Model';
```

and add after

```
$_['column_sku']                 = 'SKU';
```

Now open order_info.twig from admin/view/template/sale

Find

```
 <td class="text-left">{{ column_model }}</td>
```

Add After

```
 <td class="text-left"> {{ column_sku }}</td>
```

In the same file Find

```
 <td class="text-left">{{ product.model }}</td>
```

add after this

```
  <td class="left-left">{{ product.sku }}</td>
```

Now the Fnally find in the same file

```
 <td colspan="4" class="text-right">{{ total.title }}</td>
```

and Replace it with

```
<td colspan="5" class="text-right">{{ total.title }}</td>
```

Hope This Answer Might Help You